# Get the value of a first column after selecting data from another column

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to `angular js`.I have a table with the 4 column and 4 row. In this I have added a context menu to the 2nd column data. Here when I select the data from the 2nd column row then How can I get to know the value of the first column .

It is like

```
A      B            C       D
abc    I am happy   pqr     cyz
```

So, Here I have selected the text `"I am happy"`, then I am not able to get value `"ABC"` so, How can I do that ? And also I want user should be able to select column `B` data and only one row at a time . How can I do this ?

My code is like

```
<div contextmenu-container="meta.contextmenu">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered report-table" fixed-header>
                <thead class="text-center text-info">
                <th class="text-center">A</th>
                <th class="text-center">B</th>
                <th class="text-center">C</th>
                <th class="text-center">D</th>
                </thead>
                <tr ng-repeat="report in reports.data">
                  <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.A }}</td>
                  <td contextmenu-item="row" class="td-report-field">{{ report.attributes.field }}</td>
                    <div contextmenu="meta.contextmenu" class="dropdown contextmenu ">
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-content" role="menu">
                          <li>
                              <a role="menu" href
                              ng-click="delete()">
                              <span>delete</span>
                              </a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-if="report.attributes.message && showcheckbox" 
                    ng-bind="report.attributes.message" ng-click="getcheckedData(report.attributes.message)">
                    <span ng-if="report.attributes.message" contentEditable ng-model="report.attributes.message">
                      {{ report.attributes.message }}
                    </span>
                    <span ng-if="!report.attributes.message">{{ report.attributes.message }}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.score }}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
             </div>


$scope.deleteAnnotation = function() {      

};

{
    "data": [{
        "type": "report",
        "id": 1,
        "attributes": {
            "A": "ABC",
            "B": "I am happy",
            "C": "",
            "D": "1"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: can you provide your json

Comment: Can you create a JSfiddle for the work you have done till now. So that it will be easier to understand and solve

Comment: Just added the json.